Change Enter line break character with shift+enter line break in Python
How can I replace newline characters (\n) with a Shift+Enter equivalent in Python to maintain paragraph structure when working with text data? Are there any specific libraries or techniques to achieve this?
I want to fill the textarea with selenium.

What exactly do you mean by Shift + Enter?
if you mean to remove all \n characters and then place something else in its place the this should work -
text = ...
text2 = ""
for line in text.split_lines():
   text2 += line + [the character you want to enter]


Shift + Enter is the LF character chr(10). Also it would be preferable and simpler to use .join to form the new text.

You can't replace \n with Shift+Enter, but you can do Shift+Enter with selenium ActionChains. The code below holds down Shift and presses Enter, so if you do that every time a \n appears in the data you should get the desired effect.
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys(Key.RETURN).perform()

